# No error for wrong path when calling SaveAs2 VBA/Word 2013 with OLE

Tags: vba, com, visual-foxpro

Situation: From Visual Foxpro 9 I make a document in Word by means of OLE (COM). Functioned for the past years. Moved to new PC (W7Pro) and to Word 2013. In the runtime version the oWord.SaveAs2(...) is skipped without any error. In the development version it functioned ok.

By moving the SaveAs2 inside Word I got an error and it turned out to be an error in the path, because the mem-file where the path was stored was not transfered correctly in the runtime version.

Took about 8 hours. I know this is not a question, but would like to report it anyway.

During this process I couldn't find a way to get parameters passed from VFP9 to a function or sub in normal.dotm with the .run method. Only could call a sub without parameters.

Comment: You can write about the solution in the answer box below your question and then accept your own answer. This way the problem and solution are properly recorded in the SO system. At the moment it just shows as an unsolved problem. Putting the word "solved" in the title does not change its status - you can also get rewarded for using the system appropriately.

Comment: Mem files neither store nor transfer the paths differently between developer and runtime versions. It is just a user error not using a "name" expression for paths. (wish this question was not edited and brought to top after 2 years)

Answer (score 0):

Situation: From Visual Foxpro 9 I make a document in Word by means of OLE (COM). Functioned for the past years. Moved to new PC (W7Pro) and to Word 2013. In the runtime version the oWord.SaveAs2(...) is skipped without any error. In the development version it functioned ok.

By moving the SaveAs2 inside Word I got an error and it turned out to be an error in the path, because the mem-file where the path was stored was not transfered correctly in the runtime version.